# java.lang.StackOverflowError while calling a method

Tags: java, interface

I am learning interface behavior. i have created a interface and its implementer class, while calling method m1() i got java.lang.StackOverflowError. i dont know why. can anybody tell me proper reason behind this !!!!!!
 Here is the code :

```
public interface Employee {
     String name="Kavi Temre";
}

public class Kavi implements Employee{
    Employee e= new Kavi();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kavi kt=new Kavi();
        kt.m1();
    }

    void m1()
    {
        System.out.println(Employee.name);
        //System.out.println(e.name);
    }
}
```

both sysout give the same error : please tell me what is actually going on here ??

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    at Kavi.<init>(Kavi.java:2)
    .....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call

```
Kavi kt=new Kavi();
```

it initializes the `e` member :

```
Employee e = new Kavi();
```

which then initializes its own `e` member, which gives you an infinite chain of calls to the `Kavi` constructor. Hence the StackOverflowError.

It's equivalent to :

```
Employee e;
public Kavi ()
{
    e = new Kavi();
}
```

A constructor shouldn't call itself in an infinite loop.

Removing the `Employee e = new Kavi()` line will solve your issue. If your class must hold a reference to an `Employee`, consider passing it to the constructor :

```
public Kavi ()
{
    this.e = null;
}

public Kavi (Employee e)
{
    this.e = e;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee e = new Kavi ();
    Kavi kt=new Kavi(e);
    ...
}
```

An alternative solution is to change :

```
Employee e = new Kavi();
```

to

```
static Employee e = new Kavi();
```

That would be a valid solution if all instances of `Kavi` share the same `Employee` instance referred by `e`.

Comment: thanks eran. you are right but if put Employee e= new Kavi(); in a static block like this static { Employee e= new Kavi(); } then i didnt got any error. please tell me why this happen ??

Comment: @kavitemre When you declare the `e` variable inside a static initializer block, that block only gets executed once, when the class is initialized. Therefore it won't be executed every time you call your class's constructor. BTW, such a declaration would be useless, since this variable will become a local variable of the static initializer block, so you'll have no access to it from outside that block.

Comment: i know it. i am just exploring interface and object initialization. thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

Inside your class `Kavi` you are declaring a field `e`of type `Employee` and initialize it with a new `Kavi`object.

When creating the first instance of the class Kavi you are triggering the aforementioned initialization and create a new `Kavi` object (line 2) that also creates a new `Kavi` and so on and so on. So the problematic line is

```
Employee e= new Kavi();
```

After a good number of `Kavi` objects have been created, the stack will reach its limit and the exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks stefan for your explanation. i have a doubt if put Employee e= new Kavi(); in a static block like this static { Employee e= new Kavi(); } then i didnt got any error. please tell me why this happen ??

Comment: If `Employee e` is inside a static block then is not an object variable, but a class variable. It will be initialized only once.